# Looping through touch enabled owl carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I am trying to work with owl slider.
I have gone through the documentation but I am unable to figure out how
to loop through owl slider single slides.
I mean they work fine with pagination but with touch they stop at last slide.
**Is there a possible way to loop through touch**.
thanks.
here is the link
http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/one.html

Comment: There is no way you can do it without modifying their dragEnd event, my suggestion is to modify their code to do exactly what you want namely at line 1045 of their source code to modify it instead of a new position at the last one, to go back to the 0, and vice versa for thier less than 0 one

Comment: No solution but I suggest using slick for carousels. Really user friendly with a great API - http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the latest version of Owl carousel (2.0.0-beta.2.4), this has a `loop: true` option which allows infinite scrolling when you reach the last slide in your case.

http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/